# Using Retrofit getting response with http code 200 but empty body

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit for the first time, after the login validation I run my retrofit api call function `loginApiCall` to verify the user.
I got the response 200 even if my validation are wrong(email and password wrong), but getting the true result of this check `response.isSuccessful()` in response.

```
private void loginApiCall() {
    Call<LoginResponse> call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance().getApi().userLogin("*******@gmail.com", "****");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "no Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Here Retrofit setup for my calls

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
private Retrofit retrofit;
private RetrofitClient() {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
}

public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public QareebApiInterface getApi() {
    return retrofit.create(QareebApiInterface.class);
}
```

here is Interface for POST

```
public interface QareebApiInterface {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(WebServiceConstant.END_POINT_NEW_USER)
Call<LoginResponse> userLogin(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password
);
}
```

Here is gradle files related to retrofit

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

I have converted volley call to retrofit where only username and password was sending to the server (There is no Auth). Is there any issue of auth as i am not sending or missing anything? but if missing why response is 200?

Following is the volley call(which is working fine) which i replaced with retrofit.

```
public void  loginApiCall(final String email, final String password) {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response);
                }
            },
            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

Comment: are you sure the login api is working as you expect it? you have an interceptor that's not doing anything, you can remove it.

Comment: @takecare api is working fine in other application, i just converted it to retrofit

Comment: Did you look to response as Json? And Did you check seriliazedName in LoginResponse class?

Comment: @Beyazidy why do we need Seriliazed String name(username and password) require? I dont think so we need it. isn't ?

Comment: Your post parameters username and password. But you fetch data as LoginResponse

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan do not use **SOLVED** or **Solution** in question title or body. Please post a self-answer and accept it after 48 hours instead. This way community users can understand your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add logging to see real response

`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'`

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new 
OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
```

It's can be 200 with error description

Comment: I have already added interceptor dependency in my project, I have updated my question for gradle dependecies

Comment: the logging interceptor won't work unless you explicitly set it up. you can find out how to do that here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: @takecare I have removed the interceptor as i have not need to add token or special header

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue and on okhttp I see my JSON response.
It seems an issue on GSON parsing but can't fix it.

On debug the response is populated except that the body

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31878110)